# HighCharts Bubble dataLabels color

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to change dataLabel color on mouseOver event. Is it possible?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this and try to change the colors on mouseover.

Source: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-point-events-mouseover/

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.enableMouseTracking

```
        plotOptions: {
        series: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function () {
                        var chart = this.series.chart;
                        if (!chart.lbl) {
                            chart.lbl = chart.renderer.label('')
                                .attr({
                                    padding: 10,
                                    r: 10,
                                    fill: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                                })
                                .css({
                                    color: 'red'
                                })
                                .add();
                        }
                        chart.lbl
                            .show()
                            .attr({ 
                                text: 'x: ' + this.x + ', y: ' + this.y 
                            });
                    }
                }
            },
            events: {
                mouseOut: function () {
                    if (this.chart.lbl) {
                        this.chart.lbl.hide();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate on each datalabel and catch mouseover/mouseout action. Then call css() and set color.

```
        $.each(chart.series[0].points, function(i,point){
            this.dataLabel.on('mouseover',function(){
                point.dataLabel.css({
                    color: 'red'
                });
            }).on('mouseout',function(){
                point.dataLabel.css({
                    color: 'black'
                });
            });
        });
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Utx8g/377/